# minDate' since it isn't a known property of 'input' while setting BsDatepicker minDate from angular 6 directive

Tags: angular, typescript, directive

I have used BsDatepicker for calendar and now I am setting minDate from the directive.

I have import BsDatepickerModule too in the main module and lazy module too, but while setting minDate form angular 6 directive 
it gives error console

> minDate' since it isn't a known property of 'input Directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appCalendarValidation]',
  host: { '[minDate]': 'minDate' }
})

export class CalendarValidationDirective {
  constructor() { }

  @Input('minDate') minDate: Date;
  @HostListener('click')

  setMinimunDate() {
    const date = (new Date()).getFullYear();
    this.minDate = (new Date(date - 200, 0, 1));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a util class like

```
export class BsDatepickerMinDateUtil {
 public static getBsDatepickerMinDate() : Date{
 let dateDifference =  <Your- date>
 let minDateMonth = <your-date>
 let minmumDate: Date;
 let currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
 return minmumDate = new Date(currentYear - dateDifference , minDateMonth);
 }
```

}

And Use the value as:

```
[minDate]="bsDatepickerMinDate" in your form.
```

This may help you.